# How to get the "New Website" menu item in Expression Web 4?

Tags: microsoft-expression

I have Expression Web 4 installed but I cant see the "New Website" menu item show in this tutorial.
http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd939172.aspx

Any ideas how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are looking at obviously isn´t for Expression Web 4 especially... This button is somewhere else in Expression Web 4. It´s located at the menu `Site`

[image: Expression Web 4]